# Can two feature classes share geometry and have different attributes with ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, enterprise-geodatabase, feature-class

Is there a way for two feature class (say parent and child) to share same geometry shape but have their own set of attributes?
Features created or updated on parent feature class transfer its geometry shape to child feature class but not any of its attributes.
Both of feature class will be in same GDB and its storage type is SDE.ST_Geometry.

ArcGIS 10.3, Oracle RDBMS: 12.1.0.2

Comment: No, the geometry object is stored in the row. However you can create a related/joined aspatial table that has no geometry but points to the geometry in the spatial table. You would need to have a key field auto populated and unique (not OID) to join both tables on and use a trigger function to create new rows - but that will not help with deleted shapes.

Comment: Not familiar with SDE/Oracle, but shouldn´t it also have the possibility to use constraints when shapes get deleted? Something like "ON DELETE CASCADE".

Comment: Your reference to "parent and child" is unclear. If you mean this in the context of replication, the are you asking about Geodatabase Replication in different database instances? No two tables can share the same row data, but pushing a copy is a trivial exercise (albeit one maybe better asked in an RDBMS forum). Please [Edit] the question to specify the geometry storage type (SDO_GEOMETRY, SDE.ST_GEOMETRY, ...) and more details on the location of the "child".

Comment: @Vince both of feature class will be on same GDB hence replication is out of context. Our DB geometry storage type is SDE_ST_GEOMETRY. As per suggestion from #MichaelMiles-Stimson, I am trying a workaround.. "Creating a spatial table and creating a relationship class to relate it with feature class having geometry shape". But couldn't able to create unique ID and not touching objectID, Thought of copying objectID to one of new field using field calculator but that will not auto populate new objectID being created. please suggest.

Comment: Replication is *not* out of context, only *Geodatabase Replication*. Have you *tried* using INSERT, UPDATE, and DELETE triggers? If so, you need to update the question to include them. My *suggestion* is that you use a view on the source table, since there is no need for true replication.

Comment: No i have not tried triggers because feature class are registered as version so changes happens to delta tables and it will be difficult to define triggers for delta tables. Currently I am working on creating unique field which will serve as PK for defining relationship class. would you please help me to know how can i get a unique field in  feature class ? thanks!